# Running shell script from jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

When i try to execute the jobs from terminal it works for `one hour` without any issue. when i try to execute shell from Jenkins it works for just one minute and stops the execution. The output from Jenkins console output as follows :

```
Creating folder path in /jenkins/workspace/load_test/scripts/loadtest/loadtest1
PWD is : /jenkins/workspace/load_test/scripts/loadtest
Running  /jenkins/workspace/load_test/scripts/loadtest/loadtest1/testRestApi.sh
1495126268
1495129868
3600
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Any ideas/ suggestion to make the script run for one hour from Jenkins job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` it is commonly used for daemons. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller however this should let you run your script

Comment: I am able to run the job when i am able to run using this 'BUILD_ID=dontKillMe' but it does not stop after one hour so i would like to know how to stop it after one hour completes. thanks it worked